# Change AndroidManifest with xmltask

Tags: android, xml, ant, xmltask

I'm trying to use ant [xmltask](http://www.oopsconsultancy.com/software/xmltask/) to preprocess my AndroidManifest.xml in IntelliJ IDEA. My build.xml looks like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project name="codebase">
    <taskdef name="xmltask" classname="com.oopsconsultancy.xmltask.ant.XmlTask" classpath="xmltask.jar"/>
    <target name="main">
        <xmltask source="./AndroidManifest.template.xml" dest="./AndroidManifest1.xml">
            <uncomment path="/manifest/comment()[1]"/>
        </xmltask>
    </target>
</project>
```

And the AndroidManifest.template.xml looks like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        package="com.example"
        android:versionCode="1114222"
        android:versionName="2.2.2"
        android:installLocation="auto"
        >

    <!--<uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.BILLING"/>-->
    <!-- Some more code here -->
</manifest>
```

So I expect it to uncomment

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.BILLING"/>
```

string, but when I run it, I get Exception

```
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 71; The prefix "android" for attribute "android:name" associated with an element type "uses-permission" is not bound.
```

And the AndroidManifest1.xml leaves unchanged. What can I do with this?

Comment: Did you find out how?  I have the same problem with inserting xml into the manifest.  same unbound error.